# Microsoft Visual Studio XAML Designer is playing a tune

Tags: visual-studio, xaml-designer

I'm fearing this is slightly off topic (not a joke, though!!) but I've noticed the process "Microsoft Visual Studio XAML Designer" sometimes playing a short (between 5 and 10 seconds) tune when running a debug build of one of the projects I've been working on in Visual Studio. It doesn't happen *every* time I run a project but has happened often enough already. Because of its random nature, I don't think I'll be able to record evidence of this, however.

The tune it plays reminds me mostly of medieval tournament music, as can, for instance, be listened to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MmBrYyVhTc).

The project in question doesn't contain any sort of sound or music in itself. I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 RC and of some significant addons I've only installed Re-Sharper.

So the "question" here is: **how can I make it play, say, [punk rock](https://youtu.be/bucVwI0RfEg)**? I'd find that more suiting to my programming style :)

EDIT

I managed to capture the tune! I set up a voice recording with my phone and waited for the tune to play. After almost seven minutes of normal using of Visual Studio, I got lucky. Anyway, excuse the crappy quality: [Microsoft Visual Studio XAML Designer tune (Soundcloud)](https://soundcloud.com/tom-ladek/msvsxaml-designer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render the UI, the designer will run user code. The sound is most likely coming from some part of the application or some other 3rd party library.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it _was_ user code (kind of). More precisely, it was a webpage reference that was hardcoded as a default page in a WebBrowser control in a XAML file. That webpage runs a short Flash intro on page load so that's where the tune was coming from. The VS XAML Designer apparently loads that page when it renders the XAML for the "Design" view. What still baffles me though, is that I've never worked with that XAML (or that part of the software in general) myself so I'm not sure why the "Design" view had to be rendered at any point anyway.